# GCMouse.mice() is always empty, despite my mouse working

Tags: ios, swift, mouse, ios14, ipados

I am using the new [GCMouse.mice()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller/gcmouse/3626182-mice) API on iPadOS 14.

My Bluetooth mouse (Logitech MX Master 2S) is clearly recognized, and I can navigate the OS and even my app with it. If I go to *Settings → Accessibility → AssistiveTouch → Devices*, my mouse is right there.

However, no matter at what point I call `GCMouse.mice()`, the result is an empty list, and `GCMouse.current` is always nil.

Similarly, I listen for `GCMouseDidConnect` but it never fires.

To reproduce: I added this code to `AppDelegate.swift` in the default project template.

```swift
import UIKit
import GameController  // new

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  // new:
  @objc func showMice() { print(GCMouse.mice()) }
  @objc func newMouse(notification: Notification) { print(notification) }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // new:
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(showMice), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(newMouse), name: NSNotification.Name.GCMouseDidConnect, object: nil)

    return true
  }

  ...
```

In the console I simply see:

```
2020-09-21 21:52:52.737457+0200 MouseTest[1639:1517093] Metal API Validation Enabled
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
...
```

Is there something I'm missing? Is there maybe an entitlement I don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this seems like a hardware problem with the Logitech MX Master 2S mouse specifically. Another developer tried my code with a different Bluetooth mouse, and saw `GCMouse.mice()` get populated fine. *Yet another* developer tried my code on a difference device with the Logitech MX Master 2S mouse, and saw the same behavior I saw.

So, beware: at least *some* Bluetooth mice act wonky around the new iPadOS 14 `GCMouse` API. This is as of iOS 14.0.

Comment: Well I have the same issue with all my Logitech mice. I bet it's a iPadOS issue. What mouse do your friend have?

Comment: I've been trying with wired Logitech & HP mice and it works great! It appears they have issue with Logitech BT mice.